# htaccess 301 redirect not working with my site

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have rewrite URL via htaccess now I want to redirect that URL to another URL.

Now I want to redirect `http://www.domain.com/tag/example-page` URL to `http://www.domain.com/tag/example`

```
redirect 301 /tag/example-page http://www.domain.com/tag/example
```

Please help me regarding this issue.

Below is my rewrite rule, which I am using for short URL

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/tag/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/tag/$1 [R=301,L]` should work in that case.

Comment: thankx but not work yet

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache? Sometimes these requests are cached.

Comment: also, your 301 redirects must be placed above your rewrite rules in your htaccess file. As Shashank mentioned, clear your cache also

Comment: hi every body i try clean cash but not work this is my site `http://goo.gl/AwdW7f`

Answer (score 0):

Keep this rule as your very first rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tag/example-page/?$ /tag/example
```